# Webpushr API send_at query

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to send a browsernotification to a specific user via the api on webpushr.com.

According to the API i have to send JSON via POST with the 'send_at' key, and a UTC time string.

I've tried sending this JSON to the API.

```
{"title":"This is my message header","message":"No description for this message","target_url":"https:\/\/my.homepage.biz","send_at":"2020-03-08 00:10","sid":"REMOVED_FOR_SECURITYREASONS"}
```

The message is being recorded as it should on webpushr, the content, the 'send_at' date and everything i'm posting is OK. But the message is being delivered instantly when i POST the data.

[Here is the documentation](https://docs.webpushr.com/send-push-to-a-subscriber-id)

I'm sending it all via PHP & cURL, and i recieve this response:

```
{"status":"success","description":"Notification sent successfully.","ID":REMOVED FOR SECURITY}
```

____Edit_____
Ok, so the documentation notes that it should be delta UTC time (fx. 2019-04-03 18:00 +01:30)

I tried that aswell.. Heres my JSON i POST at UTC time 19:57

```
{"title":"{"title":"This is my message header","message":"No description for this message","target_url":"https:\/\/my.homepage.biz","send_at":"2020-03-04 19:57 +01:10","sid":"REMOVED_FOR_SECURITYREASONS"}
```

This should give me 1 hour and 10 minuttes to the notification ?

Here's the JSON response

```
{"status":"failure","type":"invalid_value","description":"Schedule date must be at least 5 minutes in future"}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You're date does not have an offset time. From the docs - *"The UTC offset is the difference in hours and minutes from Coordinated Universal Time (UTC) for a particular place and date. It is generally shown in the format ±[hh]:[mm], ±[hh][mm], or ±[hh]. So if the time being described is one hour ahead of UTC (such as the time in Berlin during the winter), the UTC offset would be "+01:00", "+0100", or simply "+01"."*

Comment: From WebPushr *"You will set this if you want to send the notification at a scheduled time in the future. The format is expressed in terms of delta to UTC. Example: 2019-10-10 19:31 **+5:30**"*

Comment: @JayBlanchard I follow you 100%. I've had the same thoughts, and tried them aswell. I'll update my question with more information....

Comment: What is UTC for your location? For example, UTC for me right now is 22:00  -5:00

Comment: I'm in Denmark, so it should be +1 until summertime (then it's +2)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation related to `send_at` prameter was incorrect and has been updated. The `send_at` should be defined in UTC format. Example: for PST schedule time of 2020-03-04 13:30 (San Francisco time), it should be expressed as `"2020-03-04 13:30 -08:00"` since PST is 8 hours behind UTC. Since you are in Denmark, you are currently 1 hour ahead of UTC (until summer time), you will therefore define `send_at` as `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM +01:00"` where `HH:MM` will be your local Denmark time.